# Does SSIS run on memory doing transformation or does it store anywhrere?

Tags: memory, ssis

I have Flat file input and my output will be flat file too. I want to know when we do transformation using flat file to flat file , does data get stored in anywhere on back end of SSIS or does it only runs on  the memory on run-time?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

As a general rule, SSIS is an in memory ETL tool. That's how it provides the high throughput by never touching disk.

Situations where it will spill to disk are when the system is under memory pressure. That can be through external factors (too many competing processes on the box), self-inflicted factors ([semi/blocking transformations](https://jorgklein.com/2008/02/28/ssis-non-blocking-semi-blocking-and-fully-blocking-components/), too many operations running in parallel), and/or "fat" data types (binary/max/LOB) in your data flows.

You can watch performance counters for ... buffers spooled/spilled something like that and if that's non-zero, then you're dumping intermediary files to disk.

Comment: Great Thanks for your answer @billinkc. How can we monitor these types of situations ?

Comment: While the package is running, you can run perfmon and look for the buffers spooled/spilled event. Within the SSIS Package itself, I don't think there's any explicit facility to detect if it's dumping to disk. Maybe there's an Information event fired but I'd honestly don't know. If it's that important for you, try and gin up a situation to see when it happens (with perfmon) and then rerun the package and make sure you review the warnings and information events fired.